# Proper way to instanciate class in godot (preload vs class_name)

Tags: godot, gdscript

As far as I am aware there are two main ways to instantiate class in gdscript 2.0.

1. Preload/load class with script and create instance:

```
var some_class = preload("res://SomeClass.gd")
...
var instance = some_class.new(...args)
```

2. Use class_name

```
# in SomeClass.gd
class_name some_class extends Object

# in place where class instantiated
var instance = some_class.new(...args)
```

Which way to create new instance of class is preferred? What are differences between two methods? Is there any reason to avoid just using `export_class` everywhere?

Comment: On a side note, it's usually a better idea to extend RefCounted instead of Object. RefCounted implements a reference counter for your object, allowing it to be garbage collected when it is no longer referenced, thus freeing up memory. When you extend Object you'll need to deallocate the memory yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `class_name` everywhere in your game code.

The differences I'm aware of are:

- `preload` can take a relative path.
- `class_name` classes are always available.
- `class_name` pollutes the global scope.

Thus, `preload` is better for reusable components. Stuff that you want to be able to take from one project to another, and without worry they will conflict with something. In other words: addons.

Thus: default to `class_name` unless you have a reason not to (and that is probably when writing addons or editor plugins).